# mvc view-unable to access nested list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of categories and each category may have subcategories. I am getting the list with correct records in my controller but if I try to use the list of subcategories in my view, it shows nothing.

Classes:

```
 public class DashboardTile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class DashboardTileBO : DashboardTile
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public List<DashboardTileBO> DashboardTiles { get; set; }
}

public class AddTileVM
{
    public List<DashboardTileBO> DashboardTiles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddTiles()
    {
        var allDashBoardTiles = BLL.PublicLayer.GetAllDashBoardTiles(SessionItems.UserId);
        var addTileVm = new AddTileVM()
        {
            DashboardTiles = allDashBoardTiles,
        };
        return PartialView(addTileVm );
    }
```

View:

```
 @model Hugo.BusinessObjects.AddTileVM
 <link href="~/Content/js/nestable/nestable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="~/Content/js/nestable/jquery.nestable.js"></script>
 <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Remove Tiles to desktop</h4>
    </div>
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddTiles", "Default",new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DashboardTiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <label class="">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(a=> Model.DashboardTiles[i].IsChecked)
                                @Model.DashboardTiles[i].Description
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        @*if (@Model.DashboardTiles[i].DashboarTiles.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (var j = 0; j < @Model.DashboardTiles[i].DashboarTiles.Count; j++)
                             {
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <label class="">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => @Model.DashboardTiles[i].DashboarTiles[j].IsChecked)
                                        @Model.DashboardTiles[i].DashboarTiles[j].Description
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            }
                        }*@
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a=> Model.DashboardTiles[i].ID)
                       }
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-tiles" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-tiles" >Update</button>
        </div>
    }
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
}
```

method to fetch list

```
   public static List<BusinessObjects.DashboardTileBO> GetAllDashBoardTiles(long userId)
    {
        using (var context = new HugoInternalEntities())
        {
var distincCategoryIds = context.DashboardTiles.Select(a => a.CategoryID).Distinct().ToList();
            var allTiles = (context.DashboardTiles.Where(a => distincCategoryIds.Contains(a.ID)).Select(x=>
                            new BusinessObjects.DashboardTileBO
                            {
                                ID = x.ID,
                                Name = x.Name,
                                Description = x.Description,
                            })).ToList();
            var list = context.DashboardUserTiles.Where(a => a.UserID == userId).Select(a => a.DashboardTileID).ToList();

            allTiles.ForEach(a => a.IsChecked = list.Contains(a.ID));
            allTiles.ForEach(a=>a.DashboardTiles=context.DashboardTiles.Where(b=>a.ID==b.CategoryID && b.ID != a.ID).Select(x=>
            new BusinessObjects.DashboardTileBO
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,
            }).ToList());
            allTiles.ForEach(a => a.DashboardTiles.ForEach(b => b.IsChecked = list.Contains(b.ID)));
            return allTiles;
        }
    }
```

In the above view my list of main categories is shown but if I uncomment my code for subcategories nothing is shown. Please see the screenshot of the list I am getting in `addTileVm`

List of tiles:

[image]

Comment: I think the issue might be with your GetAllDashBoardTiles method.Can you paste this method as well.Basically whereever you are fetching your Dashboardtiles

Comment: Are you sure that `DashboarTiles.Count > 0`? Anyway it' better to use `DashboarTiles.Count() > 0`

Comment: @Jags please check I have pasted that method too I have debugged the code and checked that I get list with 20 elements in controller

Comment: Please reduce a counter in your view

`@for (var i = 0; i < Model.DashboardTiles.Count; i++)` to
`@for (var i = 0; i < Model.DashboardTiles.Count - 1; i++)`

Are you receiving any error, exception.. use `ctrl + alt + e` and in `exception` dialog check "Common Language Runtime Exception"